# Bluetooth and Wi-Fi not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, driver, ubuntu-16.04

I'm working on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, and I would like to use my bluetooth headphones. The card is a **Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter**, can't find a proper driver to install to make it work.

This is the output of `inxi -Fxz`:

```
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: rtl8821ce port: c000 bus-ID: 04:00.0
           IF: wlp4s0 state: down mac: <filter>
```

This is the output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

And this is the output of `dmesg` that I think it's related to all of it:

```
[    2.482158] usb 1-13: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    7.740358] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    7.740365] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.740367] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.740368] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.740373] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.350597] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[    8.350599] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin
[    8.805573] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   10.876381] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[   18.872613] Bluetooth: hci0: download fw command failed (-110)
[   19.018324] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.018326] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.018328] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

I have no clue how to solve this issue, I already tried installing several drivers suggested in news related to this problem, but none of it worked. Any suggestion?

Comment: I repost this question on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, bluetooth worked when i installed blueman - Graphical bluetooth manager.

I see that my wireless network adapter is different from yours, but blueman can fix your Bluetooth problem. I have the **Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174** and i use the Ubuntu 16.04.

The blueman is a part of Ubuntu repository, so you can use this commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

When you install blueman, some dependencies are also installed. See the list of dependencies on the [official blueman package page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/x11/blueman).

Additional information about my **Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174**.
The firmware used as driver is ath10k_pci, as can see in output after run the following command:

```
sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
```

Output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0310]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:e007 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5689 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 275d:0ba6  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
cd rtw88
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/rtw88/
sudo cp  rtw8821c_fw.bin /lib/firmware/rtw88/ 
reboot
```

**Now Check wifi working or not**